# Unpack iterator into dictionary, with itertools

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, python-itertools

Is there anyway to achieve this without nesting? Right now at the moment the "config_file_main" holds 3 parameters but in reality there will be around 10. I know list comprehension can be used, but with there being 10 parameters I don't think it would be very readable. I threw "random_value" as a key for an example parameter that may remain the same for every config. It should be noted that number of files is subject to change from 1-10 files. Attenuation constants are arbitrary as well, they can be integers if need be.

Here's a working solution.

```
attenuation_scalar = [.3, .1, .2, 5]
random_value = 5

# files = ['test1']
files = ['test1', 'test2']
# files = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

for i in itertools.product(attenuation_scalar, repeat=len(files)):
    config_file_main = [] 
    for f, ii in zip(files, i):
        config_file = {
            'attenuation': ii,
            'file': f,
            'random_Value': random_value
        }


        config_file_main.append(config_file)
    # do stuff to config file
    print(config_file_main)
    print('')
```

Here's what I mean by unpacking a iterator into a dictionary.

```
attenuation_scalar = [.3, .1, .2, 5]
random_value = 5

# files = ['test1']
files = ['test1', 'test2']
# files = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

config_file_main = [] 
for i in itertools.product(attenuation_scalar, repeat=len(files)):
    config_file = {
        'attenuation': *files,
        'file': *i,
        'random_Value': random_value
        } 
    config_file_main.append(config_file)
# do stuff to config file
print(config_file_main)
print('')
```

Comment: No matter what, I think you need the nested `for` loop. I would still use a list comprehension, though. Formatted over multiple lines, it would definitely be readable even with a large number of parameters.

Comment: I don't want to make assumptions here but I think you have some mistakes in both code snips here, also poor variable naming makes it harder for others to quickly understand your program. "i" is no help, and "config_file_main" seems confusing as to what its purpose is, as you've stated it "holds three parameters", but it is a list of dicts

Comment: @HymnsForDisco where are the mistakes? The first snippet is a working solution, the second is the proposed/question. My bad on the variable naming. I added a comment "# do stuff to config file", my main question is achieving the same output as my working solution. The 3 parameters I'm referring to are "attenuation", "file" and "random_value" within the config file. Does that help by any chance?

Comment: I see you've removed the duplicate print statement on the first, but it still seems it may be an error that your first code has the print statement within the loop, and the second code has the print statement outside the loop.  Secondly it seems odd to me that you have `'attenuation': *files,` meanwhile `'files': *i`, I assumed that was an error due to the mismatching of names.

Comment: Unpacking an iterator into a dict won't help you, because the output you want isn't a dict. You're trying to build a list of dicts. Unpacking the iterator into *a* dict won't give you that. There's no unpacking syntax that will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: There is unpacking syntax for dicts, but it does something else.

Comment: @iz_ thank you, I wasn't fond of the nested for loop/list comprehension within the loop, but it seems like it's okay to have some nesting in certain situations like I do?

Comment: Nesting is not an inherently bad thing. Not only is it "ok" in many cases, it is frequently necessary for program logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
config_file_main = [dict(attenuation=ii, file=f, random_value=random_value) for i in itertools.product(attenuation_scalar, repeat=len(files))for f, ii in zip(files, i) ]
```

This will create the same output as the first code snippet, not sure I would suggest this as it could become not readable very fast.